# Comparing rows of a matrix with some row vectors

Tags: matrix, time-limit-exceeded, matlab

I have run this program for five hours and it has not yet completed. I wonder if we can make changes to reduce the computation time.

I use several for loop and this greatly increases the computation time. my goal is to compare the contents of the rows of a matrix (4435 × 2000) with 6 row vectors (1 × 2000). The comparison is made on parts of 64 values.

```
for i=1:4435          
    for j=70:2000      
        L = A(i,j);      
        j1=0;     
        j2=0;     
        j3=0;     
        j4=0;     
        j5=0;     
        j6=0;      
        for i1=70:2000  
            if D1(B(v,1),i1)==L  
                j1=i1;  
                Break  
            end  
        end

        for i2=1:2000
            if A(B(v-1,1),i2)==L
                j2=i2;
                Break
            end
        end

        for i3=1:2000
            if A(B(v-2,1),i3)==L
                j3=i3;
                Break
            end
        end

        for i4=1:2000
            if A(C(mm,1),i4)==L
                j4=i4;
                Break
            end
        end

        for i5=1:2000
            if A(C(mm-1,1),i5)==L
                j5=i5;
                Break
            end
        end

        for i6=1:2000
            if A(C(mm-2,1),i6)==L
                j6=i6;
                Break
            end
        end

        if j1>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(B(v,1),j1-63:j1)
              m_A1(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A1(i,j)=0;
           end
        end 

        if j2>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(B(v-1,1),j2-63:j2)
              m_A2(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A2(i,j)=0;
           end
        end 

        if j3>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(B(v-2,1),j3-63:j3)
              m_A3(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A3(i,j)=0;
           end
        end 

        if j4>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(C(mm,1),j4-63:j4)
              m_A4(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A4(i,j)=0;
           end
        end 

         if j5>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(C(mm-1,1),j5-63:j5)
              m_A5(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A5(i,j)=0;
           end
         end 

         if j6>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(C(mm-2,1),j6-63:j6)
              m_A6(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A6(i,j)=0;
           end
        end 

    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

In Matlab, unlike C, you have to vectorize your code.
A first step would be to understand how to use `find` like this:

```
i1=70:2000;
j1=find(D1(B(v,1),i1)==L);
```

and:

```
if j1>64             
       m_A1(i,j) = all( A(i,j-63:j)==A(B(v,1),j1-63:j1) );
end
```

You may also find `any` and `all` useful. Eventually you should be able to eliminate all the `for` loops and `if` statements.

Comment: thank you for your answer, but could you, please, also change the part of the program:     if j1>64             
           if A(i,j-63:j)==A(B(v,1),j1-63:j1)
              m_A1(i,j)=1;
           else
              m_A1(i,j)=0;
           end
        end

Comment: Here you go. See the update.